# How to get values from beego AppConfig and render it in HTML template?

Tags: web, web-applications, go, beego

I want to get value of a key defined in beego's **app.conf** and render in html pages.
As per documentation on http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/template.md I can get value of AppConfig by using config function in templates. However there is no example in documentation.

> Get the value of AppConfig. {{config configType configKey defaultValue}}. configType must be String, Bool, Int, Int64, Float, or DIY

After trying many ways I came to this:

```
<div>{{config config.String config.appname "TestDefaultValue"}}</div>
```

But I am always getting error:

```
<config>: wrong number of args for config: want 3 got 0
```

What is the correct way to use config template function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this myself. `config` template function accepts all parameters as string.

Correct way to use `config` template function is:

```
<div>{{config "String" "appname" "TestDefaultValue"}}</div>
```